# Safely reading http request headers in java

Tags: java, security, http-headers

I'm building my own HTTP webserver in java and would like to implement some security measures while reading the http request header from a socket inputstream.

I'm trying to prevent scenario's where someone sending extremely long single line headers or absurd amounts of header lines would cause memory overflows or other things you wouldn't want.

I'm currently trying to do this by reading 8kb of data into a byte array and parse all the headers within the buffer I just created.
But as far as I know this means your inputstream's current offset is always already 8kb from it's starting point, even if you had only 100bytes of header.

the code I have so far:

```
InputStream stream = socket.getInputStream();

HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

byte [] buffer = new byte[8*1024];

stream.read( buffer , 0 , 8*1024);
ByteArrayInputStream bytestream = new ByteArrayInputStream( buffer );
InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader( bytestream );
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( streamReader );

String requestline = reader.readLine();

for ( ;; )
{
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if ( line.equals( "" ) )
        break;

    String[] header = line.split( ":" , 2 );

    headers.put( header[0] , header[1] ); //TODO: check for bad header
}

//if contentlength > 0
//      read body
```

So my question is, how can I be sure that I'm reading the body data (if any) starting from the correct position in the inputstream?

*I don't exactly use streams a lot so I don't really have a feel for them and google hasn't been helpful so far*

Comment: You could look at the Apache Tomcat source code to see how they do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an answer myself. (was easier than I thought it would be)

If I were to guess it's not buffered (I've no idea when something is buffered anyway) but it works.

```
public class SafeHttpHeaderReader
{   
    public static final int MAX_READ = 8*1024;
    private InputStream stream;
    private int bytesRead;

    public SafeHttpHeaderReader(InputStream stream)
    {
        this.stream = stream;
        bytesRead = 0;
    }

    public boolean hasReachedMax()
    {
        return bytesRead >= MAX_READ;
    }

    public String readLine() throws IOException, Http400Exception
    {
        String s = "";

        while(bytesRead < MAX_READ)
        {
            String n = read();

            if(n.equals( "" ))
                break;

            if(n.equals( "\r" ))
            {
                if(read().equals( "\n" ))
                    break;

                throw new Http400Exception();
            }
            s += n;
        }

        return s;
    }

    private String read() throws IOException
    {
        byte b = readByte();

        if(b == -1)
            return "";

        return new String( new byte[]{b} , "ASCII");
    }

    private byte readByte() throws IOException
    {
        byte b = (byte) stream.read();
        bytesRead ++;
        return b;
    }
}
```